# Is there a way to only use a recursive type bound field given a condition?

Tags: java, oop, generics, design-patterns

I'm new to Java and coming from Python, so I don't have a great grasp of generics, but I am trying to make a general `Parameter` class that contains a `value` field, which can be an `int`, `float`, `string` *or an array of one of the previous types*:

```
public class Parameter<T> {
    private final String name;
    ...
    private final Utils.Range<T> range;
    private final RANGE_TYPE range_type;
    private final T value;

    public enum RANGE_TYPE {CONTINUOUS, DISCREET};
    ...

    /* constructor / builder class etc */
    ...
}
```

It also has to have a range, which I have implemented as follows:

```
public class Utils {
    /**
     * Collection of helper classes
     */
    public static class Range<T extends Comparable<T>> {
        /**
         * Generic Inclusive Range (designed for int / float / double).
         */
        private final T start;
        private final T end;

        public Range(T start, T end) {
            this.start = start;
            this.end = end;
        }

        public boolean contains(T number) {
            return (number.compareTo(start) > 0 && number.compareTo(end) < 0);
        }

    }
}
```

The data that I'm pushing into this `Parameter` class is coming from a REST API that spits out JSON for each "Block" (I also have a `Block` class that expresses the hierarchy of the blocks - basically a DAG, but each Block can contain sub-Blocks). I wanted a generic way to encapsulate this parameter data without depending directly on the data structure from the REST API.

The issue is, the generic types between the `range` field in `Parameter` class and the `Range` class itself are incompatible. I can't make the `Parameter` class extend `Comparable`, as `T` can be a container (List, ArrayList, etc). Note: In the event `T` is a container class, the range would be checked element-wise.

Am I coming at this from the wrong direction? In python I would implement this as a dict and not worry too much about the types of the values.

Comment: What's the use case for `T` being an array? How do you use it?

Comment: @ernest_k - the value field in the JSON that I'm trying to consume can be either a `float/int/etc` or a `float[]` (or even a `float[][]`), the range field is applicable element-wise in the event it's a collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any dependency between the generic type of Range and the one from Parameter?

In case not, you can separate them in 2 generic params in Parameter class as below.

```
public static class Parameter<T, R extends Comparable<R>> {
    private final String name;
    private final Range<R> range;
    private final RANGE_TYPE range_type;
    private final T value;
```

Comment: That makes sense, it didn't occur to me that you could have multiple generic params. `R` and `T` could be the same type, but in the case where `T` is an array, they can't be I don't think. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Range's generic type parameter must be Comparable. Parameter's generic type parameter is not necessarily Comparable.

Parameter must also enforce this constraint, if you need it to internally create a Range.

```
class Parameter<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

---

By the way, all classes and enums should be camel case, by convention. `RANGE_TYPE` should be `RangeType`.

Comment: Yes, that's the issue, I can't make `class Parameter<T extends Comparable<T>> `, unless arrays / lists extend `Comparable`.

Comment: Lists themselves are comparable? I think I misread https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html / https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html then.

Comment: @Aidenhjj My mistake, they aren't.

Comment: I think fundamentally your question is just missing too many details. What is a "parameter"? It needs to take some collection (list or array) and it internally it then creates a range of collections. How would you even begin to *define* a range of collections?

Comment: the range for a collection is element-wise. I'd happily accept suggestions on how to completely re-think my approach.

Comment: @Aidenhjj Is it okay for the `Parameter` to *only* work for Lists?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182815/discussion-between-aidenhjj-and-michael).